# Exception raised when invoking MembershipUser.ResetPassword() using OracleMembershipProvider

Tags: oracle, asp.net-membership

In some cases, MembershipUser.ResetPassword() raises an exception. This only happens for some users, and it's not clear why. There are no inputs to the method, so it seems like a problem internal to Oracle's membership provider implementation.

The exception text: **The provider returned an error that is not described by other MembershipCreateStatus enumeration values.**

The traceback:

```
at Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider.ResetPassword(String username, String passwordAnswer)
at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ResetPassword(String passwordAnswer)
at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ResetPassword()
...
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Today I were having the same issue. 
Answer is very simple. User account is LOCKED. Execute MembershipUser.UnlockUser() before password reset.